# ActiveJob could not find record in `test` environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activejob

*This issue only exists in `test` environment. Everything runs fine in `development` environment.*

I am facing a strange issue after recently upgrading to Rails 5.0.0.1 from Rails 4.2.7.1. Everything was working fine before this upgrade.

In one of my models, I use ActiveJob to perform a task.

```
# webhook_invocation.rb

def schedule_invocation
  WebhookRequestJob.perform_later(id)
end

def init
  remember_webhook # No DB changes
  init_errors_context # No DB changes
  flow_step_invocation.implementation = self
  flow_step_invocation.save!

  return unless calculate_expressions  # No DB changes
  calculated! # An AASM event, with no callbacks
  schedule_invocation
end
```

and in `WebhookRequestJob#perform`, I retrieve the object using the ID supplied

```
# webhook_request_job.rb

def perform(webhook_invocation_id)
  invocation = WebhookInvocation.find_by(id: webhook_invocation_id)
  invocation.run_request
end
```

The problem is that in the `#perform`, it cannot find the record (`invocation` becomes `nil`). I even tried putting `p WebhookInvocation.all` as the first line, but all it prints is an empty collection. On the other hand, if I try `p WebhookInvocation.all` in `#schedule_invocation` method, it properly prints out all the objects of `WebhookInvocation`.

There is no exception being raised, no lines of warnings either.

**Edit 1:**

I even tried passing the object directly to `#perform_later` i.e. `WebhookRequestJob.perform_later(self)`, but the received object at `#perform` is `nil`.

**Edit 2:**

I noticed that there are some messages like `Creating scope :fail. Overwriting existing method FlowStepInvocation.fail`, caused by using AASM. I eliminated them by using `create_scopes: false`. But that still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe the upgrade updated some of your gems . What is running these background jobs - sidekiq? resque? How did the versions change before and after the update? Also if it's using redis behind the scenes you should look at that as well.

Comment: @Joel_Blum Thanks for your reply. This code is running on my local machine (`Rails.env.development?` is `true`). There is no sidekiq, resque etc. enabled. Also, on local redis is not being used as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `config.active_job.queue_adapter` was set to `:inline` as default before Rails 5, but it is set to `:async` in Rails 5.

This made the specs to fail (don't know why). To resolve this, I put the following line in my `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess from the info you supplied is that you have are calling the `schedule_invocation` method in a `after_save` or `after_create` callback. Since the callback is called, ActiveJob might start processing the job even before the object is actually persisted (before `COMMIT` is done). In this case your record will not show up in the database when job is processed and you will get an empty collection or `nil`.

To fix this change your callback to `after_commit` to make sure that the `COMMIT` action has happened before you queue the job.

Comment: I've included the code from where `#schedule_invocation` is being called. This method is not being called in any callback.

Comment: @31piy can you find the object in the database right before `schedule_invocation`? when is the `init` method called

Comment: Yes, I can find that object. I had mentioned that in question. `p WebhookInvocation.all` had that object in results.